# Why does Javascript allow arithmetic by non-numbers

Tags: javascript, operators

```
var i=0;
var a={};
console.log(i*a);
console.log(0*{});
console.log({}*{});
```

results NaN, NaN, NaN

Ofcourse this can't throw a syntax error because of the dynamic natue of js, but why doesn't this at least throw a runtime error? Trying to find a bug from this took me ~15 minutes. Wouldn't throwing an exception always be desirable?

Comment: That's how JS has been designed to work. Whether it's desirable, is pretty much an opinion. Just wait, there's worse ahead, dividing by zero also produces `NaN`.

Comment: Would you expect `1/0` to throw an error as well? Or `0/0`?

Comment: @Teemu I'm not sure why NaN would be considered 'bad' in that case - although that can be explained due to *all* numbers in JavaScript being IEEE-754 floats and it uses a non-signaling NaN :}

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not considering it bad, but OP might ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does JS allow arithmetic with non-numeric values?

Because there are values that can be converted to numbers implicitly:

```
new Number(15) + "7" * {valueOf() { return 2 }} // 29
```

> Why does JS allow arithmetic with `NaN` without throwing?

Because the `NaN` value is a number, and it's purpose is exactly to do error propagation without exceptions (that are quite hard on control flow). This behavior is the same as in other languages that use floating-point values.

Now, they still could have made an exception when a conversion into a number led to `NaN`, but that's inconsistent because it disallows the purposeful usage of something like `new Number(NaN)`. And if you want such a behavior, you can still have it:

```
 class MyNumber {
     constructor (x) {
         this.value = Number(x);
     }
     valueOf() {
         if (typeof this.value != "number" || isNaN(this.value))
             throw new TypeError("not exactly a number");
         return this.value;
     }
 }

 new MyNumber(15) * new MyNumber("areadfsdf")
```

Comment: Why does it not throw upon conversion failure? The parsing functions throw exceptions, why is this different?

Comment: @Khlorghaal: Which parsing functions throw exceptions?

Comment: Whoops, I'm too used to the sane languages that all do that :/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, read [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) section 11.5.1 Applying the * Operator (first bullet point)

> If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN

Comment: Correct it doesn't throw an exception. But why not?

Comment: @Khlorghaal I meant that it doesn't allow the multiplication.

Comment: "Allow" in the sense it doesn't throw an exception, producing a result who's effects may propagate.